# Capture events of DOM elements except those with a specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of tabs and want to add `mouseover` functionality to them. I don't want this functionality to be applied to `.active`.

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <div class='tab'>my tab</div>
    <div class='tab' data-id='1'>your tab</div>
</ul>

<script>
  $('.tab').on('click',function(){
     $(this).addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

I have tried this:

```
$('.tab').not('.active').on('mouseover', function(){
```

and

```
$('.tab:not(.active)').on('mouseover', function(){
```

But neither of these work. How would I exclude that active from this functionality?

Comment: What you have should work fine, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vJP2/. Can you explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Everything works for me http://jsfiddle.net/wCRzZ/

Comment: ok - so one possible issue is that I'm adding the active via addClass in response to a click in another section. Would the syntax above handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> one possible issue is that I'm adding the active via addClass in response to a click in another section. Would the syntax above handle this?

That is the issue. When adding the `mouseover` event on load, the active class isn't present, so the `.not()` doesn't exclude anything. Instead you need to check for the class inside the handler itself.

Try this:

```
$('.tab').on('mouseover', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        // your code here
        $(this).css("background-color", "#C00");
    }
});

$(".tab:last").addClass("active");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9vJP2/2/)